# Agent job that emails from custom email table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers, cursor

I used to have triggers in my database that used `cursors` / `sp_send_dbmail` to email when certain columns were updated.  I was told this was not best practice so I created a new table called EmailNotify that contains columns like recepient, subject, body etc.  So instead the triggers now insert into this table the email I want to send.

I want to create a Job that runs every few minutes that checks this table and emails.  The item below is what I came up with but is it okay to use cursors in this case? Should the table include a sent field so I know which rows I sent? Can I change that inside the cursor?  Or would it be recommended to truncate the table afterwards?

```
DECLARE @emailSubject AS NVARCHAR(100);
DECLARE @emailRecipients AS NVARCHAR(100);
DECLARE @emailBody AS NVARCHAR(max);

DECLARE cur CURSOR LOCAL READ_ONLY FAST_FORWARD FOR
    SELECT
        recipients,
        subject,
        body
    FROM 
       EmailNotify;

OPEN cur

FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO 
    @emailRecipients,
    @emailSubject,
    @emailBody

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

        EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
                @profile_name = 'name',
                @recipients = @emailRecipients,
                @body = @emailBody,
                @body_format = 'HTML',
                @subject =  @emailSubject;

        FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO 
            @emailRecipients,
            @emailSubject,
            @emailBody
END

CLOSE cur
DEALLOCATE cur
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would

1. Add an `EmailSent(DATETIME) = NULL` column to your table
2. Create an `EmailSent` variable at the top of your proc and set it to `GETDATE()`
3. `UPDATE <YOURTABLE> SET EmailSent = @EmailSent WHERE EmailSent IS NULL`
4. Add a `WHERE EmailSent = @EmailSent` to your query for the email

You can accomplish this with a SSRS report with a subscription or data-bound subscription instead of this job, but it's really just a matter of preference. Formatting is easier in SSRS, otherwise you're messing with dynamic HTML in your message body. Been there, not pleasant.

Comment: If you like this kind of questions/answers then I bet you'll like [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) :)